# Large Text in Unity Inspector

Tags: unity

I'am building a game using the webcam where I have to step back from the screen for testing. Thus I would like to display a single value in the inspector using a larger font.

Is there a possibility to change the text size in the inspector of a single entry?

I'm currently using `[Title ("$currentState")]` which creates bold text, but does not increase text size.

Comment: Have you tried using a [PropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html) to create something like a `[LargeText]` attribute you can use on the relevant fields?

Comment: Sounds good, but seems to work differently than I expect...

Comment: Unity doesn't serialize and display property getters - you'd need to put the attribute on the backing field instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [PropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html) as proposed by @DMGregory finally works:

```cs
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (LargeTextInGUI))]
public class LargeTextInGUIDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI (Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        var style = new GUIStyle ();
        style.fontSize = 40;
        EditorGUI.LabelField (position, label.text, property.intValue.ToString(), style);
    }

    public override float GetPropertyHeight (SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        return 45;
    }
}
```

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class LargeTextInGUI : PropertyAttribute
{
}
```

```cs
public class MyClass: ScriptableObject{
    [LargeTextInGUI]
    public int currentState;
}
```

Comment: If you want both an editable field at normal size *and* a large display field, you could make this a `[RepeatWithLargeTextAttribute]`, and use a [PropertyField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.PropertyField.html) first to draw the regular control for the field, then follow up with your expanded label.